# Microsoft Bot Framework[MigrationV3V4] throws 500 Internal Server Error on endOfConversation

Tags: botframework

### Some Background

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/javascript-v3-as-skill?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#convert-the-booking-bot) Microsoft documentation sample to learn how to convert a v3 bot to a skill and to consume it from a v4 Bot.*(The link for the Git Repo's in the documentation seems to be broken, use the correct links from below)*

As provided in the documentation, I cloned the [v3-skill-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/Migration/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v3-skill-bot), [v3-booking-bot-skill](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/Migration/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v3-booking-bot-skill) and [v4-root-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/Migration/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v4-root-bot) and have almost everything working properly in my local.

### The Issue

But when the v3 skill bot calls `session.endConversation()`, I am getting an `Internal Server Error` thrown in the v3 code.
The `endOfConversation` activity is properly caught in the v4 bot and all actions are performed properly as expected.

I am not modifying the cloned code in any way except for updating the .env files.
As far as I am aware of, the `Internal Server Error` which is thrown in v3 Bot is not breaking the flow in any way.

Still, I am not sure why this is thrown and would be great if someone could provide a solution.

### Some useful snippets of the code

Pasting snippets of the code that is of concern.(This is exactly copied from the git repo)

In [v4-root-bot/rootBot.js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/Migration/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v4-root-bot/rootBot.js#L68) the onEndOfConversation event is caught properly when endConversation() is called in v3 code.

```js
this.onEndOfConversation(async (context, next) => {
    // Stop forwarding activities to Skill.
    await this.activeSkillProperty.set(context, undefined);

    // Show status message, text and value returned by the skill
    let eocActivityMessage = `Received ${ ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation }.\n\nCode: ${ context.activity.code }`;
    if (context.activity.text) {
        eocActivityMessage += `\n\nText: ${ context.activity.text }`;
    }

    if (context.activity.value) {
        eocActivityMessage += `\n\nValue: ${ JSON.stringify(context.activity.value) }`;
    }

    await context.sendActivity(eocActivityMessage);

    // We are back at the root
    const card = this.getOptionsCard();
    const message = MessageFactory.attachment(card);
    await context.sendActivity(message);

    // Save conversation state
    await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context, true);

    // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
    await next();
});
```

in the v3 Skill bot [v3-skill-bot/app.js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/Migration/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v3-skill-bot/app.js#L36) on session.endConversation(), the 500 Internal Server is thrown

```js
const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
switch (session.message.text.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'end':
    case 'stop':
        session.endConversation();
        break;
    default:
        session.send("Echo (JS V3) You said: %s", session.message.text);
        session.send('Say "end" or "stop" and I\'ll end the conversation and back to the parent.');
}
}).set('storage', inMemoryStorage);
```

Sample of the Internal Server Error which is thrown in v3 Skill bot

```sh
Error: POST to 'http://localhost:3978/api/skills/v3/conversations/emulator%3Aafa14650-acf1-11eb-8367-4f0cff212aa0%7Clivechat/activities/c189ee30-acf1-11eb-873e-0f26fb88a562' failed: [500] Internal Server Error
    at Request._callback (/Users/prabhu/Code/BotBuilder-Samples-main/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v3-booking-bot-skill/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js:722:46)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/prabhu/Code/BotBuilder-Samples-main/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v3-booking-bot-skill/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/prabhu/Code/BotBuilder-Samples-main/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v3-booking-bot-skill/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/prabhu/Code/BotBuilder-Samples-main/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v3-booking-bot-skill/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

### Update after 1 day

I managed to figure out the root cause of the issue but still no solution to fix it.

In [v4-root-bot/skillConversationIdFactory.js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/edit/main/Migration/MigrationV3V4/Node/Skills/v4-root-bot/skillConversationIdFactory.js)

```js
async deleteConversationReference(skillConversationId) {
    // if the blow line is commented, I am not getting any error
    //this.refs[skillConversationId] = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue only occurs when connecting to the parent from the Emulator.

I raised this as an issue in the BotBuilder-Samples Git Repo. [Issue # 3240](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/3240). Read the comments there to know more about it.

The workaround is to just comment out the line as mentioned below or to override v3 to not send trace after endofconversation.

```js
async deleteConversationReference(skillConversationId) {
    // if the blow line is commented, I am not getting any error
    //this.refs[skillConversationId] = undefined;
}
```